# mongodb: ... is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, mongodb

When i try to install mongodb as a windows service using the following command:

c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\bin>mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --logpath c:\wamp\bin\mongodb
\logs --logappend --dbpath c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\data --directoryperdb --install

it says that my service has been installed successfully and to use the command "net start 'MongoDB'" to start the service

so when i type the command:

"net start MongoDB"

I receive this error:

"System error 193 has occurred.

*** is not a valid Win32 application."

I have a 32bit laptop running windows 7 32bit OS and i made sure i installed the mongodb 1.6.5 32bit version

The interesting part is that i can start mongo server through command line running the command "mongod.exe"  and use "mongo.exe" to perform queries.

However, trying to run it as a service i get a windows error.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the space you have below (see [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7network/thread/be04aba0-afc0-475e-a41f-ebc399318a5d)) ...

```
c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\bin>mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --logpath c:\wamp\bin\mongodb \logs --logappend --dbpath c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\data --directoryperdb --install
```

Right here ...

```
--logpath c:\wamp\bin\mongodb \logs --logappend
```

Take the space out between **\mongodb** and **\logs** ... also make sure you are running your command prompt as "administrator" if you using Windows 7 ...

*Note if you NEED a space, use quotes around the dir path and that should fix it as well.*

Comment: you are 100% right! I'm hitting myself in the face. i was starring at the line for 20 mins trying to figure what was the problem.

thanks Justin! good eyes.

Comment: i just realized that my console wraps to a newline right where the space is located. which is probably the reason why i never noticed it.

Comment: also note: i had to add ".exe" to "c:\..\..\bin>mongod       ..."

so it would appear as so:

`c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\bin>mongod.exe --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 ...`